# -Objc -lz other linker flag in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

What does the -lz mean for the other linker flags in xcode. I have often seen this being used with -Objc or can it be used independently also ? What is it's usage ? I am using xcode 7.0.0

Comment: Start *Terminal.app* and type `man ld`.  Find the `-l` option etc.

Comment: i understand "-l" is for library but what happens when -lz is used. does it have a special meaning as i am pretty sure i don't have a library called z... as per documentation of man ld the following i could gather:                                       -lx         This option tells the linker to search for libx.dylib or
                 libx.a in the library search path.  If string x is of the
                 form y.o, then that file is searched for in the same places,
                 but without prepending `lib' or appending `.a' or `.dylib' to
                 the filename.

Comment: Hi. `-lz` = [zlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib) - it's a system lib.

Comment: @Mozilla  ohh k but why do we add -lz in other linker flags... i see zlib is added already to the link with libraries, do we still need it ?

Comment: @Nav You can keep only one location. I'm prefer via `-lz`, because in my projects i use a `*.xcconfig` files.

Comment: k thanks ... so i dont need to link it again in link libraries isn't it ?

Comment: @Nav Yes. Enough the one place - `Other linker flags` or `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mozilla answered the question for me so closing this issue